# Browser Caching?

Tags: html, caching, express, pug

It has recently come to my attention that my website is slow on the loading. I would like to take care of this in part with web caching. I have in depth experience with microprocessor L1 caches, but when it comes to a browser cache, my knowledge of caches comes to an abrupt halt. This leads into my question, which has two parts:

1. How do I go about caching an entire html page in the browser?
2. How do I go about caching a single image in the browser, like a logo?

I am using expressjs as my server language and jade as a templating language.

Note, I would appreciate an explanation for any answers.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the extensive community for node and express, fortunately there is already a simple solution available.

```
var oneDay = 86400000;
app.use(compress()); //npm install compression --compresses server response
//maxAge for cache storage
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/css/backgrounds', {maxAge: oneDay}));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/icons', {maxAge: oneDay}));
```

Immediate, significant improvement to the speed of the site!

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript has a preload function that can do this for you; however, the speed won't really be faster, overall. The stuff still has to download to the visitor. It is better to adjust the load speed by reducing the excess.

Remove any bloat from the code, minimize as much as possible, and make sure the images you're using are actually the size you have them showing in the browser. If you use a 5MB picture, but resize it in the HTML to 320x240, it still has to send the whole 5MB to the visitor before the image will display.